# Load data from a json file array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am working on trying to extract user information from a `.json` file. The file outputs user information dynamically in the following format (exactly):

```
[
    {
        "endpoint":"10.0.0.2",
        "id":1,
        "identifiers":["0x002","0x003"],
        "name":"user_one",
        "ping":21
    },
    {
        "endpoint":"10.0.0.3",
        "id":2,
        "identifiers":["0x004","0x005"],
        "name":"user_two",
        "ping":28
    }
]
```

I then have an HTML document with a select field like so

```
<select id="select"></select>
```

My goal is to collect all of the `id` and `name` fields for each user and add them to the select field as an option. Here is the code I have tried to begin with to see if I could print the data for the two people online:

```
var playerData = $.getJSON("https://example.com/file.json?jsoncallback=?");
var $select = $('#select');
$select.find('option').remove();
var listitems = '';
$.each(playerData, function(key, value) {
    listitems += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
});
$select.append(listitems);
```

Due to the limitations of the game APP I have to call it with jSON-P instead of CORS because the server blocks access-control and I can't modify the header of that app sadly. The code block above will output the following:

[image: Seems to be creating a whole bunch of dropdown options from somewhere]

Not sure if I am even calling the file correctly at this point. And once I do call it, they are stored in groups surrounded by `{}` but there is also a `[]` bracket holding everything. What am I missing with this?

Comment: what you're missing is that ajax calls are asynchronous.

Comment: added some debug and its saying its failing the getJson call.

Comment: Also `$.getJSON()` returns a promise, not the data. Read the docs  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have stated, `$.getJSON()` doesn't work like that. Try putting your code in a success callback function.

```
$.getJSON("https://example.com/file.json?jsoncallback=?", function(playerData) {
    var listitems = '';
    $.each(playerData, function(key, value) {
      listitems += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
    });
    $('#select option').remove();
    $('#select').append(listitems);
});
```

Comment: This should work but its just not returning anything for some reason so I am going to try and pass the data i want client side instead.

Comment: `$.getJSON()` fails silently if the data received is not in proper JSON format. Try `$.getJSON(...).always(function(data) { console.log(data); })` and see what you're getting back. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/